# Detener la lectura de eventos con SDL2 hasta terminar la carga de recursos

Tags: c++

¡Hola stackoverflow! Vengo a pediros ayuda con la famosa SDL2.

Como sabreis la pila donde se almacenan los eventos crece y crece constantemente a menos que se libere por ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
SDL_Event ev;

...
while(continuarJugando){

   while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev) continue;

}
```

Algo así hago en mi gameloop. El problema esta en que hasta que la ejecución de mi juego no llega al gameloop se realiza la carga de algunas imagenes con IMG_LoadTexture, cosa que imagino que no se puede hacer hasta no inicializar la SDL con SDL_INIT_VIDEO. ¿Y que pasa si inicias el sistema de video? que el sistema de eventos se activa automáticamente.

Así que lo que sufro es que mi pila de eventos crece y crece hasta que se desborda y crashea mi ejecutable porque no estoy recogiendo los eventos a la hora de cargar las imagenes.

Supongo que podría entre carga y carga de recursos incluir un bucle como el de SDL_PollEvent que he puesto más arriba. ¿Pero no sería mejor desactivar el subsistema de eventos hasta que yo lo quiera utilizar, o algo así? ¿Conocéis alguna otra solución que yo no sepa?

Muchas gracias

Comment: No conozco apenas SDL, pero Googleando no he visto en ningún lado que se especifique que `SDL_INIT_VIDEO` sea necesario para cargar imágenes. ¿Lo has probado?

Comment: No, no lo he probado Paula , pues mira cuando llegue a casa le echo un vistazo y te comento, gracias.

Comment: Vale ya le he echado un vistazo. Mira, para crear un SDL_Texture necesito un renderizador. Para crear un renderizador necesito una ventana y para crear una ventana necesito iniciar la SDL. De momento lo que tengo pensado hacer es vaciar la pila de ventos entre la carga de unos recursos y otros.